# Need Flickr API to LogOut Or Expire token

Tags: flickr

I am using flicker PHP sdk phpFlickr-3.1 to access media content into a web application. I have successfully obtained the authentication token with required grants. I need to support the logout feature in web application. The logout from web application should either logout from yahoo account or it should revoke grants form authentication token.

Is there any API to logout / expire authentication token / remove grant permission from authentication token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of an API to explicitly log out.  However, you can simply discard the [access token](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html#access_token) that you received from the OAuth workflow, once your access is complete.  This will force your application to go through the workflow again, the next time your app needs access.  Quoting from the docs, emphasis added:

> After the user authorizes your application, you can exchange the
>   approved Request Token for an Access Token. This Access Token should
>   be *stored by your application*, and used to make authorized requests to
>   Flickr.

Comment: I already tries this solution. Discarding token does not resolved issue because user is login to flickr account from browser and permitted flickr account access to the application. That's why it is not prompting for login or requesting flickr read privileges.